# NoMethodError in Ruby :: Custom Exception class

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a custom exception class as:

```
module ABC
  class XYZ < Exception

  end
end
```

I try to call my exception class in some other class as ::

```
raise ABC::XYZ "My Msg" if something != onething
```

I get the below exception:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `XYZ' for ABC:Module
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You’re just missing a comma, the line should be:

```
raise ABC::XYZ, "My Msg" if something != onething
```

Currently it’s being parsed as a method call to `XYZ` with `"My Msg"` as the parameter, which gives the error since there is no `XYZ` method.

Answer (score 1):

You need to raise an instance of `ABC::XYZ`

As you have it, the Ruby interpreter assumes you are trying to execute a method.

```
raise ABC::XYZ.new("My Msg") if something != onething
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do somehting like this:

```
if something != onething
  raise ABC::XYZ, "My Msg"
end
```

untested:
or you can do this I guess:

```
raise ABC::XYZ, "My Msg" if something != onething
```

Hope it helps!